# How to implement a wrapped custom loss in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss

I want to implement a wrapped loss function in TensorFlow 2.0, like the following:

```
def wrapped_loss(tensor1):

   def loss(y_actual,y_pred):

      mse_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(tf.math.abs(y_pred-y_actual)))
      another_error = tf.matmul(tensor1,y_pred)
      return mse_error + another_error

return loss

# Define some model called "my_model"
my_model.compile(loss=wrapped_loss(X1),
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr))
```

I have 10000 training samples. Therefore y_pred and y_actual have 10000 samples. In my application, the tensor X1 also has 10000 samples and "another_error" has to be calculated with the correct samples accordingly.

The above implementation gives me errors because "Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors".

My ultimate aim is to ensure that:
   1) "y_pred" is fit to "y_actual" data that I provide, 
   AND
   2) "y_pred" also needs to satisfy another optimization goal which has to be calculated using external 
   tensors (eg. X1).

How do I implement this successfully?